# sl4a dialogCreateDatePicker()

Tags: sl4a

How can I close `dialogCreateDatePicker()`? After using button screen is inactive and black.

My example:

```
import sl4a
droid = sl4a.Android()
droid.dialogCreateDatePicker()
droid.dialogShow()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close it with:

```
droid.dialogDismiss()
```